# Убрать отступ в Activity

Tags: android

Как убрать верхний отступ к активити? Белая область сверху

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: код разметки то приложите

Comment: Надо смотреть в разметку и/или в стили и/или в настройки отображения превью разметки. Для начала надо проверить, воспроизводится ли проблема на реальном девайсе и/или в эмуляторе при запуске приложения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а с safe area никак не связано?

Comment: На реальном устройстве проверяю

Comment: @Qwertiy, не очень понимаю о чём речь(

Comment: @НатальяСергеевна, вы имеете в виду, что проверяете в данный момент и позже напишите что получилось или вы имеете в виду, что только на реальном устройстве и проверяете и проблема на нём и была изначально обнаружена? Наверное первое, т.к. приложенные вами картинки похожи на превью студии, а не на скриншоты с девайса/эмулятора.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ну современные телефоны любят делать со скруглёнными углами и вырезом под камеру. Соответственно, есть весь экран и есть безопасная область, про которую гарантируется, что всё, что в ней находится, будет видно. Возможно либо активити по умолчанию подстраивается под безопасную область, либо телефон загоняет в неё всё приложение из-за того, что в манифесте чего-то не хватает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, насколько мне известно, оно наоборот будет по умолчанию под вырезы залезать и надо специально прописывать insets для правильного отображения

Comment: Проверялось на превью в студии и на реальном устройстве. В обеих случаях есть отступ.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю вот 7-ую строчку надо убрать. Она добавляет внутренний отступ сверху в корневую разметку.

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```